# Why is the c++ input file stream checked twice here?

Tags: c++, io

Here is a snippet from a c++ tutorial:

```
// istream::get example
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  char str[256];

  std::cout << "Enter the name of an existing text file: ";
  std::cin.get (str,256);    // get c-string

  std::ifstream is(str);     // open file

  while (is.good())          // loop while extraction from file is possible
  {
    char c = is.get();       // get character from file
    if (is.good())
      std::cout << c;
  }

  is.close();                // close file

  return 0;
}
```

Notice `is.good()` appeared twice, first with `while`, then with `if`.

Link to the example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Comment: This is a poor example of file I/O in C++. I would not recommend the tutorial from which you found this program.

Comment: Care to elaborate why?

Comment: You're supposed to check if the input succeeded *after* performing the input. The condition in the `while` loop is checking if the stream is `good()` *before* the input actually occurs. Moreover, `std::string` is the preferred construct for manipulating dynamically-sized strings, not C-style strings which require the use of archaic input methods such as `.get()`, `.getline()`, etc, and their respective overloads.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: [Same thing](http://ideone.com/rWwdTb), but faster and safer and easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the c++ input file stream checked twice here?

The fact of the matter is that it is *unnecessarily* checked twice. If the second inner `if (is.good())` passes, then the outer `while (is.good())` will always pass as well. The author of the code needed some way of looping, and he incorrectly assumed that a `while (is.good())` is an appropriate condition because it will stop the loop when the stream fails to extract. But this is only half-true. `while (is.good())` is never the correct way to perform the extraction.

You have to perform the input first and then check if it succeeded. Otherwise it is possible to perform a failed extraction, use the result of that extraction and receive unwanted behavior from your program. The correct way to do it is by using the extraction *itself* as the condition. The input operator will return a reference to the stream, and then it will turn into a boolean returning true if the previous read suceeded, or false otherwise:

```
while (is.get(c))
{
    std::cout << c;
}
```

The variable `c` is also not outside of the loop. You can enclose the `while()` loop in a block or use a `for()` loop instead:

```
for (char c; is.get(c); )
{
    std::cout << c;
}
```

But it seems that this code is attempting to write all the content from the file to standard output. Reading a character one-by-one is the way shown here, but you can also use stream iterators or the buffer overload of [`std::ostream::operator<<()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) as well.

There are two more problems I see in this code. Namely:

- `std::string` is the preferred construct for manipulating dynamically-sized strings, not C-style strings which require the use of archaic input methods such as `.get()`, `.getline()`, etc, and their respective overloads.
- Manually closing a file is usually unneeded. The stream will close itself at the end of the scope in which it was created. You probably only want to close the file yourself to check if it succeeds or to reopen the stream with a different file or openmode.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, that in `while (is.good())`, checks if it has reached EOF (End Of File). If not, it doesn't enter the while loop. Once entered in while(), it means that it have at least one character remained for the instruction `char c = is.get();`.

What the second if() does is that it doesn't allow to print the last character read, because after a `char c = is.get();`, the file may reach EOF. In case it does, the character is not printed.

For example, let's say you have this file:

```
"Just an example!"
```

Now, if you had just:

```
while (is.good())          // loop while extraction from file is possible
{
    char c = is.get();       // get character from file
    std::cout << c;
}
```

the output would be: `"Just an example! "`. The last space is the EOF character (which is the last character read).

But with:

```
while (is.good())          // loop while extraction from file is possible
{
    char c = is.get();       // get character from file
    if (is.good())
        std::cout << c;
}
```

the output would be: `"Just an example!"`, which is what you would expect it to be.